# Como unir varios pdf en 1 solo

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy tratando de unir varios pdf en 1, tengo una lista de url de pdf y la idea es mesclarlos en uno solo.

Intento con esto:

La lista de string tiene:

```
http://dlls.medezweb.com/resources/432714927725926.pdf
http://dlls.medezweb.com/resources/432318982047222.pdf
http://dlls.medezweb.com/resources/432365550934607.pdf
```

Y la variable outfile tiene:

```
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/dlls.medezweb.com/resources/notegeneratedbyprint.pdf
```

Aquí mi código:

```
public void UnirListaPdf(List<String> InFiles, String OutFile)
    {
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(OutFile, FileMode.Create))
        using (Document doc = new Document())
        using (PdfCopy pdf = new PdfCopy(doc, stream))
        {
            doc.Open();

            PdfReader reader = null;
            PdfImportedPage page = null;
            InFiles.ForEach(file =>
            {
                reader = new PdfReader(file);
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                {
                    page = pdf.GetImportedPage(reader, i + 1);
                    pdf.AddPage(page);
                }
                pdf.FreeReader(reader);
                reader.Close();
                File.Delete(file);
            });
        }
```

Esto produce el siguiente error:

> No se admiten los formatos de URI

Comment: No será porque la variable outfile `C:/inetpub/wwwroot/dlls.medezweb.com/resources/notegeneratedbyprint.pdf"`tiene unas `"`al final?

Comment: hola disculpa aca no lo tengo con la comilla ya lo arregle

Comment: ok, borro mi comentario XD

Comment: y si cambias los slash `/`por backslash  \ en la variable outfile

Comment: probare esa variante

Comment: ¿Qué librería estás usando?

Comment: perfecto ahora si me los une, gracias Levi Arista

Comment: estoy usando itextsharp